# lowLightBoostSupported is never true for any device on the iphone 5s

Tags: iphone, ios7, avfoundation

I've tried setting up the back facing camera at 1920x1080 with both the 420v and 420f formats (what the hell is the difference between the two?) and in both cases lowLightBoostSupported is false. Has Apple disabled it for the 5s for some reason or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I fixed this myself lol. Originally I was setting the AVCaptureSession preset to AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh, setting it to AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto instead fixed the problem.